# create a dict using numbers as keys and values from ints stored in a list in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am doing [Problem 8](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8) on Project Euler, what I want to do next is create a dict with keys from 1 - 1000 and values being each int from digits.

I have tried various methods including trying to use range from 1-1001 to create keys and nested for loop  iterating over digits, then trying intDict[k] = j where k is number from  the range loop and j is from the  digits loop but cannot seem to get it right.
How can this be achieved?
Thanks.

My code so far:

```
def lrgProdOf5Numbers():
intDict = {}
highest = 0
f= open("1000dig.txt","r")
d = f.read()
f.close()
digits = [int(e) for e in str(d) ] #convert each number in string  to int
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*edit

I see. Your text file is a block of numbers copied from the problem. This should work. As someone else mentioned, I think you probably just missed clearing newlines.

```
with open('1000dig.txt', 'r') as f:
    num_string = ''.join((line.strip() for line in f.readlines()))

d = {i: digit for i, digit in enumerate(num_string)}
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: Close to what I want, the keys are correct but I want the values to come from digits which contains 1000 ints. So basically I want keys from 1 to 1000 where key 1 has values of digits[0], key 2 has value digits[1] etc...

Comment: That is it exactly but it was not missing clear newlines, I used read() and the txt file is one long line of all 1000 numbers so there is no newline. your solution works on my original code as " d = {i: digit for i, digit in enumerate(d)}". Thanks again, I forgot about enumerate completely.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is the problem?  Are you getting any errors?

You might need to remove new line characters from 'd' if you're seeing errors in your list comprehension.

Update (based on kobejohn's answer and your response):

```
d = {i: digits[int(i)] for i in range(15)}
```

Comment: my list comprehension is fine, I made the text file into one long line of numbers as to avoid having to split or mess around with the string.

Comment: If you're not having any issues creating the comprehension then you should be able to loop (either via comprehension or standard for loop) and create the dictionary from the index and the value in your digits array.  I'm assuming that in your question your '==' should actually be '='.

Comment: when I get to double figures in keys, the values become two digits i.e 12:[3,7], when keys are three values become 3 digits. What I want is a mapping of each key,value pair  to correspond to position of each int in my list "digits". i.e first three ints in digits are 7,3,1 so 1:[7],2:[3],3[1] etc..

Comment: See updated, this should work.  Also, for what you are describing seems like a list would suffice.

Comment: NP, don't forget to mark either of the answers provided as the solution (I think kobejohn's more appropriately answers your question).